# Property 'login' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth' ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, ionic3

Iam trying to create a login page using firebase in ionic.I have imported al the neccessary componenets but i get the error Property 'login' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth' in the login method. Please help!

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';



@Component({
  selector:'page-login',
  templateUrl:'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage{
  email: any;
  password: any;
  constructor(public NavCtrl: NavController,public NavParams,public angfire: AngularFireAuth){

  }
ionViewDidLoad(){
  console.log('ionViewDidload LoginPage');

}
login(){
  this.angfire.login({
    email:this.angfire,
    password:this.password
  },

  })

}

  }
```

Comment: In login method put `console.log(this.angfire)` and see what you got.

Comment: Done that
login(){
  this.angfire.login({
    console.log(this.angfire)
    email:this.angfire,
    password:this.password
  },
  {
    provider:AUTH_PROVIDERS
  }   but the error is still there

Comment: I mean login(){console.log(this.angfire)}.;)

Answer (score 0):

For AngularFire2 try this

`signInWithFacebook() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
  }`